# Add css If checkbox checked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im using a data-attribute from an input checkbox to add a background image to the element `#checkbox1` if the checkbox is checked.

What does I have to do with this function to hide the background image if the checkbox is not checked.

**HTML**

```
<div id="checkbox1"></div>

<input data-image="url(http://www.siwikultur.de/kulturpur/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/schneider.jpg)" type="checkbox" id="check1">
<label for="check1">USB-Stick-Halterung</label>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script> 
$('#check1').on('change', function () {
$("#checkbox1").css("background-image", ($('#check1:checked').data("image")));
});  
</script>
```

Comment: If you could put the `checkbox` before your `div` you can do it with just CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the button is checked with the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-type) property. If it is, display the image, if it's not, set `background-image` to `none`.

```
$('#check1').on('change', function () {
    $("#checkbox1").css("background-image", this.checked ? this.dataset.image : 'none');
});
```